# How to clean krausen off of ceilings?

Tags: cleaning, krausen, blow-off

Woke up this morning to an unhappy surprise:

[image: the brew blew]

Getting the ceiling clean has proven to be quite the challenge, since the krausen had dried off before I got to it.  Can anyone share techniques that have worked for them in this situation?

As it stands, I'm considering just burning down the house, collecting the insurance, and starting over.

Comment: LoL this is priceless.

Comment: I just hope that is beer and not the baby....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All humor aside it should clean easily with mild soap and water.  I've found that dish soap 1:20 ratio in a spray bottle does well on latex paint for all kinds of mishaps. Don't use soaps with bleach. Test a small area for discoloring, but allow to dry before you decide. My paint does change color when wet but returns to normal once dry.

Spray and let soak to soften the krausen, then it should wipe off with damp cloth.

Comment: Soap and water indeed did the trick.  I definitely think this situation calls for all available humor, though :-)

Comment: @DrewShafer glad you didn't have to raze your home and start over.

Comment: @DrewShafer also hope you corrected the clogged airlock issue for future batches.